# Can't find the bug in this jQuery code

Tags: php, jquery

I have the following code, which, upon the press of a certain button, should validate for an email address (this functionality works already), and then should try to post my form, and if it gets back "Error", it should show an error. I think I'm mixing up PHP and JS somewhere.

```
$('#recoverSub').live('click',function() {
        $("#recoverPost").validate({
            rules: {
                recoverField: {
                    email: true
                }
            },
            messages:{
                recoverField: {
                    email: "Not a valid email."
                }
            }
        });
        if($("#recoverPost").valid())
        {
            $.post('php/recoverPost.php', $('#recoverPost').serialize(), function(){
                function(data) {
                    if(data != "Error")
                    {
                        $('#recoverPost').hide();
                        $('#success').show();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        echo "This email is not in our records.";
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better way to achieve what you are trying to do:

```
$(function() {
    $('#recoverPost').validate({
        rules: {
            recoverField: {
                 email: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            recoverField: {
                email: "Not a valid email."
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            // the form was valid => post it with AJAX
            $.post('php/recoverPost.php', $(form).serialize(), function(data) {
                if(data != 'Error') {
                    $('#recoverPost').hide();
                    $('#success').show();
                }
                else {
                    alert("This email is not in our records.");
                }
            });
        }
    });    
});
```

Answer (score 5):

```
else
{
   echo "This email is not in our records.";
}
```

You probably meant to use `alert` instead of `echo`:

```
alert("This email is not in our records.");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 echo "This email is not in our records.";
```

That's php, just as you thought. Use this instead:

```
alert("this email is not in our records.";
```

Answer (score 1):

in `$.post` you have included function twice, the first does not get passed `data` so the second has no chance...

Should read:

```
$('#recoverSub').live('click',function() {
        $("#recoverPost").validate({
            rules: {
                recoverField: {
                    email: true
                }
            },
            messages:{
                recoverField: {
                    email: "Not a valid email."
                }
            }
        });
        if($("#recoverPost").valid())
        {
            $.post('php/recoverPost.php', $('#recoverPost').serialize(), function(data){
                    if(data != "Error")
                    {
                        $('#recoverPost').hide();
                        $('#success').show();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        alert( "This email is not in our records." );
                    }
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: And the echo instead of alert